# Android's progress_medium.xml Error

Tags: android

I can't seem to get this to work:

[image]

The error:

[image]

By the red X it states:

```
Multiple annotions found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'framesCount' in package 'android'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'framesDuration' in package 'android'
```

Comment: In the error, it says, paraphrased, `framesCount is not found in package Android`. Maybe it's `android:layout:framesCount`? Just a guess.

Comment: I'll take a look, this is from the official Android SDK so it seems weird :/

Comment: Sorry mate, got a invalid token error when i did that!